# overwrite Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

Some of my Ubuntu 16.04 installation files were corrupted due to some hardware issues (CPU overheating) , now the hardware was fixed, but the installation was done on a bad hardware and due to memory corruption some files were damaged and I don't know which files.
How do I overwrite all the binary files with their current version? What would be the command to do so? I don't want to reinstall everything from zero, I already have a system with needed configuration.

Comment: Reinstalling is the best approach.

Comment: I agree that reinstalling is probably much easier and faster than to identify and replace all the damaged files.

Comment: @MichaelBay, but to reinstall you have to backup /home , and my /home partition is so large that it wouldn't fit any storage medium I have

Comment: I found that apt-get install --reinstall will work, and you can get list of packages from dpkg.log , I guess I just need to parse the dpkg.log and extract filenames, and that is it, right?

Comment: You can reinstall without formating `/home` if it's a distinct partition or, if not, just don't format root. Of course, better and safer to have backups but as long as you know what you're doing and not check format in the root partition.

Comment: @MichaelBay, but the risk of clicking wrong button and erasing everything is high, I never did reinstallation before, so I am afraid going this way

Comment: I suggest that you get some storage media (for example an external hard disk drive), where you backup your current system (or at least all data, that you cannot afford to lose), and after that you can reinstall Ubuntu.